# How to detect changes of Itemscontrol UI event when I Update Itemsource?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have tabcontrol like this..

```
<TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTab}" Name="TabControlAll">
    <TabItem Header="Hal 1" Style="{StaticResource AzureTabItem}">
        <kor:Halaman1 DataContext="{Binding RTDetail}"/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Hal 2" Style="{StaticResource AzureTabItem}" >
        <kor:Halaman2 />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Hal 3" Style="{StaticResource AzureTabItem}">
        <kor:Halaman3/>
    </TabItem>
    ...
    <TabItem Header="Hal 12" x:Name="Hal12" Style="{StaticResource AzureTabItem}">
        <kor:Halaman12b x:Name="Halaman12b"/>
    ...
```

The visual picture you can see like this :[image: tabcontrol wpf]

And `Halaman12` usercontrol you can see like this xaml :

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <kor:Halaman12a Width="300"></kor:Halaman12a>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="ICHal12b" ItemsSource="{Binding ListART}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <kor:Halaman12b DataContext="{Binding}">

                    </kor:Halaman12b>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>



    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

How I can get all the text boxes in `Halaman12b`? And I wanna set properties  textboxes after Itemscontrol UI Generated like Uppercase, Color, and many more.

But When I updated `ListART` data there still no UI generated when I check in my VM

```
private ObservableCollection<ART> listART;
public ObservableCollection<ART> ListART{
     set{
        this.listART=value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ListART");
        var itemscontrol= windows.Halaman12b.ICHal12b;
        for(int i=0;i<itemscontrol.Items.Count;i++){
            ContentPresenter content=itemscontrol.ItemsContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
            List<TextBox> listTextbox=TreeHelper.FindChildren<TextBox>(content);
        }

     }
}
```

And `content` still empty.. How to get UI updated from data updated through `itemssource`?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but..... you're doing it all wrong. Delete all those tabs and set the TabControl.ItemsSource to a proper IEnumerable<T> contaning your ViewModels, and use DataTemplates to define which view render for each VM. And also the ViewModels must NOT deal with UI stuff, use DataBinding instead.

Comment: but I Don't get the right solution how to get all textboxes using ViewModels structure. I have so many textboxes there and the purposes I do this because I want before all control can be entry I have to set properties each textbox using my data contains all variable that bind to textbox. For example textbox R1 will be match in my database for variable R1 with properties of textbox including Alphanumeric, numberic, case, length and etc.. Do you have an Idea?

Comment: All I see in your screenshot is a couple of nested `ItemsControl`s, starting by the `TabControl`. In WPF, whatever UI elements you need to show data on need to have their corresponding data element inside a ViewModel. Therefore what you need here is to create the ViewModels with the corresponding data collections.